# OCR from picture in clipboard

Tags: windows, ocr

I need fast method to get English text from picture that I have in clipboard for everyday life and preferable run on windows. I was trying to use paste and extract text from OneNote, but it recognition is horrible. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/595660/is-there-a-utility-to-do-ocr-on-images-on-the-windows-clipboard

Also, 
[this](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/) seems to be an alternative: